# Como faço para deixar o background com greyscale, mas os elementos dele na mesma cor original?

Tags: html, css, filter

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>bluantinoo CSS Grayscale Bg Image Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
        float: left;
        color: white;
    }
     .grayscale {
         background: url(https://aquitemplacas.com.br/img/produtos/g/36-atencao-area-de-teste.jpg);
         -moz-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
         -o-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
         -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
         filter: gray;
         filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
     }

    .nongrayscale {
        background: url(https://aquitemplacas.com.br/img/produtos/g/36-atencao-area-de-teste.jpg);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nongrayscale">
        this is a non-grayscale of the bg image
        <button style="background-color: blue">teste</button>
    </div>
    <div class="grayscale">
        this is a grayscale of the bg image
        <button style="background-color: blue">teste</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que o botão fique azul mesmo com o filtro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode criar um pseudo-elemento `::before` na `div.grayscale` com o background e aplicar o filtro apenas nele:

```css
div {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 5px;
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   float: left;
   color: white;
}

.grayscale {
   position: relative;
}

.grayscale::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: url(https://aquitemplacas.com.br/img/produtos/g/36-atencao-area-de-teste.jpg);
   filter: gray;
   filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
   -moz-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
   -o-filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   z-index: -1;
}

.nongrayscale {
   background: url(https://aquitemplacas.com.br/img/produtos/g/36-atencao-area-de-teste.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="nongrayscale">
  this is a non-grayscale of the bg image
  <button style="background-color: blue">teste</button>
</div>
<div class="grayscale">
  this is a grayscale of the bg image
  <button style="background-color: blue">teste</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado , deu certo :)

Comment: De nada. Veja como agradecer no [tour].